# Brute force with NULLs

Tags: c

Does anyone know how to write a brute force program where if, say, the lenght is 4, in the beginning, the string would be a\0\0\0, b\0\0\0,..., ab\0\0 and so on, ie keeping its NULLs.
My question is for a password cracking homework.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO isn't here to write your homework for you...

Comment: Yes, I know how.

Comment: If you want help with your homework, you should really state what programming language you are required to use, and your attempt at the solution (your code that does not yet quite work).  Folks would be much more inclined to help.

Comment: Most likely someone does. I don't, but I guess I could find out if I spent a few seconds thinking about it.

Comment: If I knew what a "brute force program" was, and what you were planning to do, I almost certainly would know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm:

1. memset it all to null.
2. Increment the first character.
3. Repeat step 2 until the first character overflows.
4. Increment the second character
5. Go back to step 2 and repeat until the second character overlows.
6. Increment the third character.
7. You get the idea...

I leave the implementation up to you. It's your homework.